# R plyr, data.table, apply certain columns of data.frame

Tags: r, data.table, plyr, apply

I am looking for ways to speed up my code. I am looking into the `apply`/`ply` methods as well as `data.table`. Unfortunately, I am running into problems.

Here is a *small* sample data:

```
ids1   <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2)
ids2   <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4)
chars1 <- c("aa", " bb ", "__cc__", "dd  ", "__ee", NA,NA, "n/a")
chars2 <- c("vv", "_ ww_", "  xx  ", "yy__", "  zz", NA, "n/a", "n/a")
data   <- data.frame(col1 = ids1, col2 = ids2, 
                 col3 = chars1, col4 = chars2, 
          stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Here is a solution using loops:

```
library("plyr")
cols_to_fix <- c("col3","col4")
for (i in 1:length(cols_to_fix)) {
  data[,cols_to_fix[i]] <- gsub("_", "", data[,cols_to_fix[i]])
  data[,cols_to_fix[i]] <- gsub(" ", "", data[,cols_to_fix[i]])
  data[,cols_to_fix[i]] <- ifelse(data[,cols_to_fix[i]]=="n/a", NA, data[,cols_to_fix[i]])
}
```

I initially looked at `ddply`, but some methods I want to use only take vectors.  Hence, I cannot figure out how to do `ddply` across just certain columns one-by-one.

Also, I have been looking at `laply`, but I want to return the original `data.frame` with the changes. Can anyone help me? Thank you.

---

Based on the suggestions from earlier, here is what I tried to use from the `plyr` package.

**Option 1:**

```
data[,cols_to_fix] <- aaply(data[,cols_to_fix],2, function(x){
   x <- gsub("_", "", x,perl=TRUE)
   x <- gsub(" ", "", x,perl=TRUE)
   x <- ifelse(x=="n/a", NA, x)
},.progress = "text",.drop = FALSE)
```

**Option 2:**

```
data[,cols_to_fix] <- alply(data[,cols_to_fix],2, function(x){
   x <- gsub("_", "", x,perl=TRUE)
   x <- gsub(" ", "", x,perl=TRUE)
   x <- ifelse(x=="n/a", NA, x)
},.progress = "text")
```

**Option 3:**

```
data[,cols_to_fix] <- adply(data[,cols_to_fix],2, function(x){
   x <- gsub("_", "", x,perl=TRUE)
   x <- gsub(" ", "", x,perl=TRUE)
   x <- ifelse(x=="n/a", NA, x)
},.progress = "text")
```

None of these are giving me the correct answer.

`apply` works great, but my data is very large and the progress bars from `plyr` package would be a very nice. Thanks again.

Comment: how big is "very large"? Could you provide a sample data corresponding to your real data dimensions? Progress bars are needed when an operation takes hours to finish. The only bottlenecks here are `gsub` and the numerous copies during assignment (the latter of which can be avoided by assignment by reference). Providing real data dimensions would definitely help.

Comment: @Arun progress bars are useful for tasks >5s because it helps you calibrate how long it will take.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a `data.table` solution using `set`.

```
require(data.table)
DT <- data.table(data)
for (j in cols_to_fix) {
    set(DT, i=NULL, j=j, value=gsub("[ _]", "", DT[[j]], perl=TRUE))
    set(DT, i=which(DT[[j]] == "n/a"), j=j, value=NA_character_)
}

DT
#    col1 col2 col3 col4
# 1:    1    1   aa   vv
# 2:    1    2   bb   ww
# 3:    1    3   cc   xx
# 4:    1    4   dd   yy
# 5:    2    1   ee   zz
# 6:    2    2   NA   NA
# 7:    2    3   NA   NA
# 8:    2    4   NA   NA
```

> First line reads: set in DT for all i(=NULL), and column=j the value gsub(..).
>   Second line reads: set in DT where i(=condn) and column=j with value NA_character_.

Note: Using PCRE (`perl=TRUE`) has nice speed-up, especially on bigger vectors.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a `data.table` solution, should be faster if your table is large.
The concept of := is an "update" of the columns. I believe that because of this you aren't copying the table internally again as a "normal" dataframe solution would.

```
require(data.table)
DT <- data.table(data)

fxn = function(col) {
  col = gsub("[ _]", "", col, perl = TRUE)
  col[which(col == "n/a")] <- NA_character_
  col
}

cols = c("col3", "col4");

# lapply your function
DT[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, fxn), .SDcols = cols]
print(DT)
```

Comment: +1 also checkout `?set`. It avoids the `[.data.table` overhead and is therefore tad faster. Especially useful for looping through each column and updating values (by reference).

Comment: i've tried to use the ```set()``` function for this but could come up with a working answer. I haven't found an example where a function is applied  to the value call inside ```set()```. Please fell free to edit the answer.

Comment: I wrote an answer earlier using `set` and then deleted it. I've undeleted it now. Since your real data, you say, is quite big, it might be quite fast. Let me know what you find (if you manage to benchmark all these answers). Hopefully it helps.

Comment: I see how it works now. This is actually not my question, but i found the use of set instructive anyway, thanks for the answer!

Comment: Sure! Realised late that I wrote "your" instead of "OP's". Couldn't edit.

Comment: @Arun there is no `[.data.table` overhead issue here - any speed gains you saw after using `set` were probably due to a slower function used here (edited now); in my tests this was always faster than the set loop

Comment: @eddi, not entirely. [Here's a gist](https://gist.github.com/arunsrinivasan/8408180). Running `set` (without for-loop) seems faster. But with a loop, it does get slower. I'm guessing it's due to for-loop. Maybe, not sure. If it's the case, we should move it to C.

Comment: @Arun fair enough, agreed - you can see the overhead in a single column case, but since the `[.data.table` solution doesn't loop on `[.data.table` that overhead is a 1-time cost only (and so is not a big deal, just like in most other `data.table` solutions)

Comment: @eddi, exactly. But if we get `set` to take vector of columns in `j` and `loop` in `C`, I'm guessing, it'll slide ahead. Not sure. Will test it when I've sometime.

Comment: @eddi, just realised that we can do the same with `set` - it takes a vector of columns in `j` as well!

Answer (score 4):

No need for loops (`for` or `*ply`):

```
tmp <- gsub("[_ ]", "", as.matrix(data[,cols_to_fix]), perl=TRUE)
tmp[tmp=="n/a"] <- NA
data[,cols_to_fix] <- tmp
```

### Benchmarks

I only benchmark Arun's data.table solution and my matrix solution. I assume that many columns need to be fixed.

**Benchmark code:**

```
options(stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

set.seed(45)
K <- 1000; N <- 1e5
foo <- function(K) paste(sample(c(letters, "_", " "), 8, replace=TRUE), collapse="")
bar <- function(K) replicate(K, foo(), simplify=TRUE)
data <- data.frame(id1=sample(5, K, TRUE), 
                   id2=sample(5, K, TRUE)
)
data <- cbind(data, matrix(sample(bar(K), N, TRUE), ncol=N/K))

cols_to_fix <- as.character(seq_len(N/K))
library(data.table)

benchfun <- function() {
  time1 <- system.time({
    DT <- data.table(data)
    for (j in cols_to_fix) {
      set(DT, i=NULL, j=j, value=gsub("[ _]", "", DT[[j]], perl=TRUE))
      set(DT, i=which(DT[[j]] == "n/a"), j=j, value=NA_character_)
    }
  })

  data2 <- data
  time2 <- system.time({
    tmp <- gsub("[_ ]", "", as.matrix(data2[,cols_to_fix]), perl=TRUE)
    tmp[tmp=="n/a"] <- NA   
    data2[,cols_to_fix] <- tmp
  })

  list(identical= identical(as.data.frame(DT), data2),
       data.table_timing= time1[[3]],
       matrix_timing=time2[[3]])
}

replicate(3, benchfun())
```

**Benchmark results:**

```
#100 columns to fix, nrow=1e5
#                  [,1]   [,2]  [,3]  
#identical         TRUE   TRUE  TRUE  
#data.table_timing 6.001  5.571 5.602 
#matrix_timing     17.906 17.21 18.343

#1000 columns to fix, nrow=1e4
#                  [,1]   [,2]   [,3]  
#identical         TRUE   TRUE   TRUE  
#data.table_timing 4.509  4.574  4.857 
#matrix_timing     13.604 14.219 13.234

#1000 columns to fix, nrow=100
#                  [,1]  [,2]  [,3] 
#identical         TRUE  TRUE  TRUE 
#data.table_timing 0.052 0.052 0.055
#matrix_timing     0.134 0.128 0.127

#100 columns to fix, nrow=1e5 and including 
#data1 <- as.data.frame(DT) in the timing
#                           [,1]  [,2]  [,3]   [,4]   [,5]   [,6]   [,7]   [,8]   [,9]   [,10] 
#identical                  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE  
#data.table_timing          5.642 5.58  5.762  5.382  5.419  5.633  5.508  5.578  5.634  5.397 
#data.table_returnDF_timing 5.973 5.808 5.817  5.705  5.736  5.841  5.759  5.833  5.689  5.669 
#matrix_timing              20.89 20.3  19.988 20.271 19.177 19.676 20.836 20.098 20.005 19.409
```

data.table is faster only by a factor of three. This advantage could probably be even smaller, if we decide to change the data structure (as the data.table solution does) and keep it a matrix.

Comment: I dint see that OP was dealing with big data. Here, there's a copy made during col subset, as.matrix, `<-(tmp)`, `<-(tmp)` (2nd line) and `<-(data)` (last line). Probably quite costly.. I'm curious. I'll benchmark later if OP doesn't.

Comment: @Arun We might be able to reduce the number of copies if we don't insist on having a data.frame in the end. Also, I expected that data.table performs better, but the matrix solution performs quite well in comparison.

Comment: when you time `DT <- data.table(data)` in your function, I'd expect you also time the final conversion to `data.frame`, since that's the desired output. The point is about the effect of making copies (and part of it comes from your conversion to `matrix` to leverage it's performance). So what's the point if the conversion takes too much time? That's more or less what I'd like to address.

Comment: Even then, when you change N to 1e7, DT takes 13 sec, and the matrix output takes 26 sec. That's just '2x'. But 'times' can be a bit misleading. Especially when it's in the order or many seconds/minutes.

Comment: @Arun No, I don't time `as.data.frame(DT)` since imho it would be stupid to turn a data.table back into an ordinary data.frame. I know that this simple benchmarking procedure is not optimal, but I think it's sufficient here. However, the conclusion is that data.table is faster than the base R solution, but not by an order of magnitude.

Comment: Roland, as I said, the purpose is to see the *effect of copy*. The question becomes is it worthy (on huge data) to type convert to `matrix` from `data.frame` and back again? What you've effectively done is to avoid the last copy, which makes this question unanswerable without bias. And if you're interested in returning a `data.frame` from `data.table`, you can do that *by reference*. Look at `as.data.frame.data.table` (and just remove the `copy` part). I wanted to bring this point along to anyone who maybe looking at your benchmarks.

Comment: Also I don't think it's stupid to convert a DT back to DF. If your objective is to improve speed in already existing code, but don't want to put the effort to change the way DT subsets (using `with=FALSE`, no `drop` yet etc..), it's perfectly reasonable to convert to DT and back to DF if it's a time-consuming operation / the trade-off is agreeable (especially when DF -> DT -> DF can be done by reference).

Comment: I think your data never gets 1e5 or 1e4 rows. Your dimensions are set on `K` (=1000). The rows are therefore always 1000...?

Comment: Sorry, but what should N and K be to get 1e5 * 100?

Comment: @Arun See my last edit to the question concerning the timing with returning a data.frame. It doesn't matter much for medium sized data. Also K==nrow and N==nrow*ncol.

Comment: @Arun Btw., if I had massive data and I needed to do this more often I would concentrate on replacing `gsub` and the NA creation with an Rcpp function. There is probably the best potential for a speed-up.

Comment: Are you saying that you'll implement `gsub` in Rcpp (or perhaps it's already available..? sorry not a RCPP user)? What exactly do you think you'll gain by doing that? Rather where do you think you can get faster there? It's already an internal function...

Comment: I don't think you'll gain a speed-up (if any, not significant) by (re)implementing `gsub` or taking care of n/a -> NA. You'll gain speed-up because you can work on NAM(2) objects without copying. Essentially by reference. And I don't see what Rcpp has to offer different than `set` - as it's just a simple loop + assignment.. What am I missing here? Where do you think you'll gain more speed using Rcpp on this task?

Comment: @Arun Well, if I specifically replace ` ` and `_`, I should be able to do that faster than a function that can replace arbitrary characters using regex. Also, as you said with Rcpp I could do all modifications in place without copies. But I haven't really looked into this as I don't need this kind of functionality and normally don't have massive data.

Comment: I don't think that'll be more efficient than a regex engine. You've to know the position of those characters on each character element on 1e7*100 values. I don't think it'll be faster and I don't think that's the bottleneck (when using `data.frame`) here. Yes, using RCPP allows you to avoid copies. But that's no different from `set`. That's why I said I don't see a potential for further speed-up with Rcpp for this task.

Comment: Anyhow, I'm running the benchmark now. Not sure when it'll be over :). Will edit as soon as it's done.

Comment: Just noticed that using gsub with `fixed` two times is faster than using `perl=TRUE` in 1 go.

Comment: @Arun Ah, didn't think about that. `fixed` already implements my idea, no need for Rcpp then. How much faster is it with decent sized input?

Comment: On 1e5*100, it takes 5.5s with perl=TRUE and 1.7 (for `_`)+ .7 (for ' ') with fixed.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do this with regular old `apply`, which will call your cleanup function on each column (margin=2):

```
fxn = function(col) {
  col <- gsub("_", "", col)
  col <- gsub(" ", "", col)
  col <- ifelse(col=="n/a", NA, col)
  return(col)
}
data[,cols_to_fix] <- apply(data[,cols_to_fix], 2, fxn)
data
#   col1 col2 col3 col4
# 1    1    1   aa   vv
# 2    1    2   bb   ww
# 3    1    3   cc   xx
# 4    1    4   dd   yy
# 5    2    1   ee   zz
# 6    2    2 <NA> <NA>
# 7    2    3 <NA> <NA>
# 8    2    4 <NA> <NA>
```

Edit: it sounds like you're requiring the use of the `plyr` package. I'm not an expert in `plyr`, but this seemed to work:

```
library(plyr)
data[,cols_to_fix] <- t(laply(data[,cols_to_fix], fxn))
```

Comment: What about using one of the functions from the plyr package? It has some abilities (i.e., progress bars) that I really like.

Comment: I tried using aaply and alply, which are suppose to be similar to apply but I'm not getting the right answers.

Comment: @Brad edit your code with what you tried to do; hard to help otherwise.

Comment: Brodie, thanks for the suggestion.  I put my revised code in the original post.  Both @josilber and your suggestion works great but I cannot figure out the alternative with plyr.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a benchmark of all the different answers:

#### First, all the answers as separate functions:

#### 1) Arun's

```
arun <- function(data, cols_to_fix) {
    DT <- data.table(data)
    for (j in cols_to_fix) {
        set(DT, i=NULL, j=j, value=gsub("[ _]", "", DT[[j]], perl=TRUE))
        set(DT, i=which(DT[[j]] == "n/a"), j=j, value=NA_character_)
    }
    return(DT)
}
```

#### 2) Martin's

```
martin <- function(data, cols) {
    DT <- data.table(data)    
    colfun = function(col) {
        col <- gsub("_", "", col)
        col <- gsub(" ", "", col)
        col <- ifelse(col=="n/a", NA, col)
    }
    DT[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, colfun), .SDcols = cols]
    return(DT)
}
```

#### 3) Roland's

```
roland <- function(data, cols_to_fix) {
    tmp <- gsub("[_ ]", "", as.matrix(data[,cols_to_fix]))
    tmp[tmp=="n/a"] <- NA   
    data[,cols_to_fix] <- tmp
    return(data)
}
```

#### 4) BrodieG's

```
brodieg <- function(data, cols_to_fix) {
    fix_fun <- function(x) gsub("(_| )", "", ifelse(x == "n/a", NA_character_, x))
    data[, cols_to_fix] <- apply(data[, cols_to_fix], 2, fix_fun)
    return(data)
}
```

#### 5) Josilber's

```
josilber <- function(data, cols_to_fix) {
    colfun2 <- function(col) {
        col <- gsub("_", "", col)
        col <- gsub(" ", "", col)
        col <- ifelse(col=="n/a", NA, col)
        return(col)
    }
    data[,cols_to_fix] <- apply(data[,cols_to_fix], 2, colfun2)
    return(data)
}
```

#### 2) benchmarking function:

We'll run this function 3 times and take the minimum of the run (removes cache effects) to be the runtime:

```
bench <- function(data, cols_to_fix) {
    ans <- c( 
        system.time(arun(data, cols_to_fix))["elapsed"], 
        system.time(martin(data, cols_to_fix))["elapsed"], 
        system.time(roland(data, cols_to_fix))["elapsed"], 
        system.time(brodieg(data, cols_to_fix))["elapsed"],
        system.time(josilber(data, cols_to_fix))["elapsed"]
    )
}
```

#### 3) On (slightly) big data with just 2 cols to fix (like in OP's example here):

```
require(data.table)
set.seed(45)
K <- 1000; N <- 1e5
foo <- function(K) paste(sample(c(letters, "_", " "), 8, replace=TRUE), collapse="")
bar <- function(K) replicate(K, foo(), simplify=TRUE)
data <- data.frame(id1=sample(5, N, TRUE), 
                   id2=sample(5, N, TRUE), 
                   col3=sample(bar(K), N, TRUE), 
                   col4=sample(bar(K), N, TRUE)
        )

rown <- c("arun", "martin", "roland", "brodieg", "josilber")
coln <- paste("run", 1:3, sep="")
cols_to_fix <- c("col3","col4")
ans <- matrix(0L, nrow=5L, ncol=3L)
for (i in 1:3) {
    print(i)
    ans[, i] <- bench(data, cols_to_fix)
}
rownames(ans) <- rown
colnames(ans) <- coln

#           run1  run2  run3
# arun     0.149 0.140 0.142
# martin   0.643 0.629 0.621
# roland   1.741 1.708 1.761
# brodieg  1.926 1.919 1.899
# josilber 2.067 2.041 2.162
```

Comment: I don't think it makes sense to benchmark this with only two columns.

Answer (score 1):

The `apply` version is the way to go.  Looks like @josilber came up with the same answer, but this one is slightly different (note regexp).

```
fix_fun <- function(x) gsub("(_| )", "", ifelse(x == "n/a", NA_character_, x))
data[, cols_to_fix] <- apply(data[, cols_to_fix], 2, fix_fun)
```

More importantly, generally you want to use `ddply` and `data.table` when you want to do [split-apply-combine](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v40/i01/paper) analysis.  In this case, all your data belongs to the same group (there aren't any subgroups you're doing anything different with), so you might as well use `apply`.

The `2` at the center of the `apply` statement means we want to subset the input by the 2nd dimension, and pass the result (in this case vectors, each representing a column from your data frame in `cols_to_fix`) to the function that does the work.  `apply` then re-assembles the result, and we assign it back to the columns in `cols_to_fix`.  If we had used `1` instead, `apply` would have passed the rows in our data frame to the function.  Here is the result:

```
data
#   col1 col2 col3 col4
# 1    1    1   aa   vv
# 2    1    2   bb   ww
# 3    1    3   cc   xx
# 4    1    4   dd   yy
# 5    2    1   ee   zz
# 6    2    2 <NA> <NA>
# 7    2    3 <NA> <NA>
# 8    2    4 <NA> <NA>
```

If you do have sub-groups, then I recommend you use `data.table`.  Once you get used to the syntax it's hard to beat for convenience and speed.  It will also do efficient joins across data sets.

Comment: Small correction: `data.table` is **not** a `**split**-apply-combine` approach. This misconception seems to have come up somehow. It doesn't split the huge data first and then apply. That'll be particularly terrible on big data (with presumably too many levels) both in computation time + space complexity. Instead `data.table` only allocates memory for the largest group, **once**. Then, it reuses the same memory cleverly (memory footprint is less) and evaluates function while looping thro' each group from `C` (for speed).

Comment: @Arun, thanks for the background details.  I would still say that `data.table` is split-apply-combine when using `by` from a _conceptual_ perspective.  What the underlying implementation is doesn't really matter from that point of view.  Even from a technical perspective, you are still splitting the original data, you are doing so iteratively instead of with an actual split.  Clearly there is big difference performance wise, but again, from an end user perspective, it's still essentially a split.  You are just being really clever about minimizing the footprint of the split.

Comment: And please, don't take this to be a criticism of `data.table` in any way.  I think `data.table` is the most underrated package in R.  And I don't say that because `data.table` is rated low, but rather, because `data.table` should be at the top of almost any "best packages in R" listing.

Comment: It does when you use it along with `ddply` in the same sentence. Because `ddply` first `splits` the entire data - stores the split data in a variable before apply+combine. This gives a wrong impression of what's going on under-the-hood. Reg. your *conceptual* perspective, then *everything* is split-apply-combine, isn't it? Including a *for-loop* - for Ex:  `x <- 1:100; y=integer(100L); for (i in 1:100) {tmp=x[i]; tmp2=tmp*2; y[i]=tmp2 }` the data isn't actually being split here.. but by your definition, it's still "splitting" the original data. I disagree.I dint take your points the wrong way.

Comment: I think your for loop is a degenerate case, but yes.  A more meaningful example: `vec <- sample(letters, 260, rep=T); vec2 <- runif(260); for(i in seq_along(letters)) vec3[i] <- sum(ifelse(vec == letters[i], vec, 0))`.  Whether `data.table` did it this way, or with an actual `split`, or how it actually does it doesn't matter from an _analytical_ conceptual perspective.  What matters is the idea of operating on groups separately and re-assembling the result.  There is massive performance difference, but as a _user_ I shouldn't have to care about the actual implementation other than it's fast.

Comment: I disagree. `df <- data.frame(x=1:10, y=1:10); lapply(1:10, function(i) df$y[i]); lapply(unname(split(df, df$x)), function(a) a$y[1])` are not the same, to me. I'm not talking just about performance. The first case of `lapply` is *not* **split**-apply-combine, probably subset-apply-combine. The second case is a strict example of `split-apply-combine`. I see this as a difference.

Comment: I guess what I'm trying to say is: **order matters** (if not to you, to me :) ). In `s-a-c`, the data is split first, whatever function to apply is applied next and then combined. However, it doesn't work the same way here. To best describe this order would be: get groups first (1:10) -> subset by group (`df$y[..]`) -> apply (nothing in the ex: above) -> combine (done internally for `lapply`).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45011/discussion-between-brodieg-and-arun)